# In Sulu CMS, enabling Monolog has no effect

Tags: symfony, sulu

For a Sulu project, I want to enable Logging. The Monolog Bundle is installed.

This is my config/packages/monolog.yaml

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    logs:
      type: stream
      path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
      level: debug
```

I inject the LoggerInterface in my class:

```
   public function __construct(
        protected readonly LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger->debug('Hello World');
        $this->logger->error('Hello World');

    }
```

My expectation is to get 2 times "Hello World" in var/logs/dev.log. But I get no entries in the Log file. Changing the path doesn't have any effect. I also changed file permissions, also without effect. So, is this some Sulu issue or am I doing something wrong?